# Use S3 as a database by reading and writing in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, aws-glue

We use S3 for all our data. Most of them are structured and stored as parquet files in partitioned folders. Until now we have been mainly using EMR and the direct S3 paths to access and process the data.

I want to introduce some structure into the whole architecture while keeping everything serverless, so I was thinking of using AWS Glue Data Catalog as a central metastore to act as an abstract layer over the data on S3 in order to facilitate querying. I also like to have Athena as a very nice and easy tool to make use of this especially for our analysts.

However we also need to process the data and output the results into S3 again. This means on one hand ETL transformations and on the other hand aggregations, e.g. collect statistics, perform some counts on various levels, etc. and store them on tables.

As hoc querying with Athena does the job very well and it's automatically scalable, but the problem with that is that we can't use it for automated jobs and insert the results into another S3 Glue table. Although Athena has a simple option to store the results in S3, this defeats the whole purpose of having an abstract SQL layer on top of the data when it comes to storing the results as you would with SQL on a normal database.

On the other hand, AWS Glue does provide ETL capabilities but that is in Spark and python which requires code and not simply SQL.

So my question is: is there a product or approach in AWS that would allow querying AND inserting data by using S3 as storage and possibly ony SQL for operations? Keeping in mind also serverless, so kind of Athena but also for outputting or inserting into other tables (also existing tables).

As a bonus I would also like to create views on top of the tables to provide another layer of security and logic into the model, and ideally work with these views instead of / in addition to the tables. Any recommendation for this too is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on Athena's shortcomings that you're facing?

Comment: I added a comment on the answer below, hope this also answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of ETL transformation you want to do on your input data and write it on S3 again? Is it just simple aggregation? Can all those transformation you want be written as SQL query in Athena? In that case, you use CREATE TABLE as to write the query output to a different Athena table which will write a new set of files in S3 for you automatically. I have written about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54114789/simplest-tool-in-aws-for-very-simple-transform-in-etl/54126319#54126319) and Athena documentation has lots of details too.

Comment: Well one scenario is to gather some statistics, such as counts on different aggregation levels, maybe on a daily basis, and store them in a stats table. Another scenario would be to filter and clean up some data and store them in a cleaned up table. The problem with CTAS, beside the technical limitations is especially the fact that it can't insert directly onto an existing table, and the S3 output path should be empty. Which means some additional steps are required to e.g. copy the output into a folder where the files for all days are, so it can be used as a table.

Comment: For the CSV output that Athena always generates the same applies, that some post-processing steps are necessary to integrate the output into one historic table. I would really like to use serverless SQL, so is there any alternative in AWS, or if Athena is the best solution, what I'm hoping for, then what would be the recommended process to integrate the results into another Athena(Glue Data Catalog)-accessible table. The whole process is going to be automated, probably lambda, so what is the simplest way to run an Athena query from lambda, and insert results into a table?

Comment: You are right with the Athena CTAS limitations. However, if your Athena write is append only, you can mimic that by writing a new file in the same AWS folder that the Athena table is pointing to. As long as its the same structure, Athena will read all the files inside the folder. Or if you want to use CTAS, you can delete the CTAS folder, run CTAS, then move the new files from the CTAS location to the actual location. The following link may give you some additional clue which might be helpful https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1538

Answer (score 0):

In glue, you can use pysql to write sql commands.

> df.createOrReplaceTempView('table_name')
>
> df1 = spark.sql(query)

Comment: Yes, but Glue still doesn't completely automatically scale,you still need to specify the amount of nodes, and that's what I want to avoid, beside the fact that you still need python code.